# JavaScript Mixed Content Work Around

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I'm trying to make access data from [OMDB API](http://www.omdbapi.com/) but I'm having trouble with mixed content images. OMDB draws its data from IMDB, which forbids use of its https images, and so all image sources are prefixed http by necessity.

For example, the JSON for Do the Right Thing provides the src as follows:

```
"Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODA2MjU1NTI1MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTU4ODIwMjE@._V1_SX300.jpg"
```

When running the code below the images show, at least on Chrome and iOS Safari , but on Chrome I get the following warning message: `Mixed Content: The page at 'https://run.plnkr.co/zv3BGVk31NLTM0Nh/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BMTI1OTk5MTI3N15BMl5BanBnXkFtZTcwNDI3NTEyMQ@@._V1_SX300.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.`

This is that code:

```
function getMovieInfo(myMoviesTitle, myMoviesYear, isLast) {  
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = "https://www.omdbapi.com/?i&t=" + myMoviesTitle + "&y=" + myMoviesYear + "&plot=short&r=json";

  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
      var movieInfo = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);

      if (!movieInfo.Error) {
        makeMovieList(myMoviesTitle, movieInfo);
      }

      if (isLast) {
        // Runs DOM manipulation functions
      }
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function makeMovieList(myMoviesTitle, movieInfo) {
  // Appends information from omdbapi.com to DOM.
  var movie = document.createElement('li');
  movie.className = 'movie';

  var thumbnail = document.createElement('img');
  thumbnail.className = 'thumbnail';
  thumbnail.src = movieInfo.Poster;
  movie.appendChild(thumbnail);
```

I've tried with CORS as well, which works a treat on Plnkr on Chrome (no error messages at all) but doesn't seem to run on iOS or when I upload my code to Github `main.js:232 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://giles-taylor.github.io/js-movie-finder/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=the+seven+year+itch&y=undefined&plot=short&r=json'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.`

```
function getMovieInfo(myMoviesTitle, myMoviesYear, isLast) {
  var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var url = 'http://www.omdbapi.com/?t=' + myMoviesTitle + '&y=' + myMoviesYear + '&plot=short&r=json';

  if ('withCredentials' in req) {
    req.open('GET', url, true);
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (req.readyState === 4) {
        if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
          var movieInfo = JSON.parse(req.responseText);

          if (!movieInfo.Error) {
            console.log(movieInfo);
            makeMovieList(movieInfo);
          }
          if (isLast) {
            // Runs DOM manipulation functions
          }
        } else {
          // Handle error case
        }
      }
    };
    req.send();
  }
}

function makeMovieList(myMoviesTitle, movieInfo) {
  // as above
}
```

Can anyone suggest a workaround to make these images show securely (and without console warning)? Thanks!

Comment: so using `https://www.omdbapi.com/` doesn't work? - because you say IMDB doesn't allow https, but you access ombdapi using http instead of https - not sure where IMDB comes into play

Comment: Sorry, perhaps I didn't make that clear enough. Whether you use http://www.omdbapi.com/ or http://www.omdbapi.com/ the image src specified in the JSON is from http. Eg: "Poster":"http://ia.media-imdb.com/images/M/MV5BODA2MjU1NTI1MV5BMl5BanBnXkFtZTgwOTU4ODIwMjE@._V1_SX300.jpg".

Comment: ahh, sorry, my bad

Answer (score 1):

Basically mixed content is a big no-no because it undermines the security of https - [More info](https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2014/03/19/https-mixed-content-still-the-easiest-way-to-break-ssl).  As long as you continue to serve mixed content, you run the risk of browsers changing default settings and blocking stuff more or less at will, let alone experiencing consistency across browsers.

You basically have two options (neither of which are great)

- Stop serving your main site over https
- Proxy the request from your server to OMDB and then serve it yourself over https (which will massively increase your bandwidth usage)

Answer (score -1):

Just remove protocol from the image path. 
From `https://imagepath` to `//imagepath`

`thumbnail.src = movieInfo.Poster.replace(/^https?:/, '');`

Comment: Hi, the image path is `http` rather than `https` to begin with. I've tried swapping out the `http` but Chrome seems to add `https` as default, leading to the same issue of forbidden access. Thanks!

Comment: If you remove protocol whatever http or https, chrome will put the same protocol as your page.